# How do I add a new search filter to use with my Item Buckets?

Tags: content-search, buckets

I want to add a search filter which can be used for building search queries in Sitecore as per described in [the documentation](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/content_authoring/searching/filters_and_operations/the_search_filters). The search filter should filter by inherited templates.

I have followed the description [here](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/82/developing/developing_with_sitecore/search_and_item_buckets/add_new_search_filters_and_alias_filters):

1. In the content tree, navigate to
   /sitecore/system/Settings/Buckets/Search Types. Sitecore recommends
   that you add new search filters in the User Defined folder.
2. Select the User Defined folder, and on the Home tab, in the Insert
   group click Field Search Type. Give the new search type an
   appropriate name. This is the name that users enter in the search
   box to apply the filter. For example: if you name the search type
   Date, the user must type in Date: in the search box to apply the
   filter. The name is case sensitive.
3. In the new search type item, in the Search Type section, in the
   Control Type field select the type of control that is most
   appropriate for your search.
4. In the Display Text field, enter an appropriate text and ensure that
   the wording is consistent with all the other search filters. This
   text is displayed in the drop-down menu when users browse the search
   filters.
5. If you want to apply a custom syntax to the Control Type field to
   create specific output., enter this in the Web Method field. For
   example, if the Control Type field is a calendar, the Web Method
   field can make a request to a web service to tell Sitecore to
   display a calendar control that only allows you to select a date
   from the last 2 calendar years.

However, the filter doesn't appear when I try to use it:
[image: No filter named inherit]

I can see an XHR request to https://url/sitecore/shell/Applications/Buckets/ItemBucket.asmx/GetAllSearchFilters

Which returns all the filters in a JSON format, where mine is not included. The full response can be posted per request.

The data entered in the Field Type Search item is as follows:

- Icon: `/sitecore/shell/Applications/Buckets/images/text.png`
- Name: `inherited`
- Field: `_templatesimplemented`
- Control Type: `Auto Suggest`
- Control Type Parameter:
- Display Text: `Search by Base Template`
- Web Method: `ItemBucket.asmx/GetTemplates`
- Client Side Hook: `id`

The question is, what am I missing, to configure a Search Filter?

Comment: Which version of Sitecore are you on? I just followed the exact instructions with the data you entered and seems to work fine in 8.1 u3

Comment: I am actually on 8.1 u3. Maybe it is because I placed it in the User Defined folder. Did you do that as well?

Comment: Yes I did that as well. The only difference I can see is that the control type is called `Auto Suggest List`. There is no `Auto Suggest` option

Comment: How are you testing it?

Comment: It is indeed called `Auto Suggest List`, that is a typo on my behalf.

Comment: I am testing it by opening the content editor, selecting the frontpage, pressing the search icon and typing "i" to see if it auto completes "inherited". Also I see if it is available in the dropdown under Search Filters. As a last resort, i also look at the json response of the request to GetAllSearchFilters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the working examples from K. Heye and christian-hagelid, I realized that I had an assumption, and had created the Field Search Type in the Core database, where all the items lies as well.

However, it works by creating it directly in the master database.

Comment: I'd suggest rewording this so it's a bit clearer, and then accepting as your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Can you try moving your item to the root folder?
/sitecore/system/Settings/Buckets/Search Types

I think Sitecore doesn't pick up the ones in the User Defined folder by default.

Tried adding it myself in 8.1 update 3 and I see the search type:
[image]

Comment: I tried this, but unfortunately it did not change anything.

Comment: Tried it myself now, see screenshot. It shows up in my version.